# How to fix jquery-ui rails autocomplete error(turbolinks:load) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, materialize, jquery-rails

I'm working on autocomplete part in rails. I am using 'jquery-ui-rails' gem. while using `$(document).ready` it is working but it I use `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {}` it is not working because of materialize-sprockets.

If I remove //= require materialize-sprockets in application.js then it working. if I add that line then it is not working. I need materialize-sprockets for design purpose.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported 
runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read 
more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

_form.html.erb

```
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category_id %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :category_name, data: { autocomplete_source: 
  categories_path} %>
  </div>
```

categories_controller.rb

```
  def index
  @categories = Category.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%# 
  {params[:term]}%")
  render json: @categories.map(&:name)
  end
```

product.js

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
$("input#product_category_name").autocomplete({
source: $('#product_category_name').data('autocomplete-source')
});
})
```

routes.rb

```
resources :products
resources :categories
```

How to use $( document ).on('turbolinks:load') with
    //= require materialize-sprockets ?

Comment: Try to move `require materialize-sprockets` below `require turbolinks` in application.js

Comment: @Vasilisa I tried it but still it not working.